# Regular expression is not matching empty character

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have these lines of text `grep` is searching:

```
629-732-5225
(224) 662-6288
(772) 732-6333
(743)223-6992
104-692-7385
```

And this is the command I'm using to match all of the above:

```
grep "(\?[0-9]\{3\})\?[ -][0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4}" *.txt
```

And this is the output:

```
h1.txt: 629-732-5225
h2.txt: (224) 662-6288
h3.txt: (772) 732-6333
h5.txt: 104-692-7385
```

It didn't match with text from `h4.txt`. What differs is that there is not space after the closing parenthesis. I thought the `[ -]` would cover that. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching either a space, or a hyphen. You need either a space, or a hyphen, or nothing.

Use `[ -]?` to make the match optional.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure it's `?`? Escaping it as `\?` worked for me.

Comment: `?` is a quantifier, matches 0 or 1 times. You want `?`, not `\?`.

Comment: But when I did `[ -]?` nothing came up for me... The tutorial I got this from even used `\?`.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the shell I'm running it on?

Comment: `?` wasn't part of the original BRE spec so some tools (e.g. some grep, sed) require a `\?` to give it it's RE meaning for backward compatibility.